# Why does our Git-Tree look so messed up

Tags: git, tfs

the following picture is showing a part of our current Git-Tree.

What we dont really understand is how it keeps getting so messed up.

Keep in mind that this is all one branch, the lowest node being the 'main-master-node' and the other nodes are also on the master-branch but still they look like they are different branches.

We are using Visual Studio 2017 and the TFS for Git.

We are getting totally confused by this and need to always check thrice to see if it is the master-branch or a different one.

Are we doing something wrong or is it normal like this for everyone?

[image: Our Git-Tree]

Comment: The dark dots seem to be merge commits, the lighter dots are regular commits. When you say this "is all one branch", do you mean that all changes were commited directly on the master branch? Commiting on master branches on different computers and merging those into the servers' master branch could lead to a structure like this.

Comment: @kowsky Yes, the dark dots are merges. We are all working on different computers but we are all committing to the same server.

Comment: Why should this mess up the tree though?

Comment: So why the confusion? What about this tree is "messed up" in your opinion? You did merge branches into each other, so the commit graph structure is no surprise?! If you merge a branch `A` into another branch `B`, the commits of both branches now are part of the history of branch `B`, but you can still see that they were developed in parallel. If you do not want parallel branches in your history, you should use `rebase` instead of `merge`.

Comment: But we are all committing to the same branch, why do we need to merge in the first place? There arent even conflicts in these committs

Comment: Probably, some developers are using `git pull` instead of `git pull --rebase` when integrating upstream changes into their local branch. `git pull` creates merge commits (multi parent commits) while `git pull --rebase` rebases the local commits onto the branch tip fetched from the upstream (resulting in linear history). `git pull` can also be configured to use rebase per default by setting git config variable `pull.rebase` to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `master` branch on the remote repository. Bob clones the repository and works and commits on his local `master` branch. Eve also clones the repository and works and commits on her local `master` branch. She's pretty quick, so she pushes her commits to the remote repository; the remote `master` gets updated with her commits. When Bob finally finishes what he did, he cannot just push to the remote `master` branch, since he diverged: he has commits on his `master` that the remote has not, and at the same time the remote has commits that Bob's `master` has not (those from Eve).

What now? Bob can either *merge* his master branch into the remote master branch, making his commits available by creating a merge commit that "unites" both branches, or he can *rebase* his local `master` onto the remote `master`. The latter will put his own commits on top of the remote `master`s commits, as if he would have commited after Eve's changes were already incorporated.

The details of this process depend on your git server management tool of choice, and I can't say anything about TFS, but this is why it is necessary to either merge or rebase, even when you all work on the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is one of the main reasons why I advise not to use Visual Studio git feature and prefer an external tool.

By default, VS is doing a `git pull` (so, with a merge) to sync your local branch with the remote repository. Which is a bad thing to do when you are working on the same branch than the one you sync with.

Most of the times, you do a `git pull --rebase` to sync (and keep a linear history) and keep the merge only when merging a branch in another branch.

You could set a git settings ('pull.rebase' if I remember well) to make VS do a rebase, when you sync.

I think that in the last version of VS, you could also do a rebase, even if it not very user friendly.

Or you could use a better git tool (for example Gitextensions : https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions ) that permit you to better understand how git works, what is happening and also do more advanced things!